# Any examples of using Ruby and the Bing Ads API v2.0?

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, bing, bing-api

I'm trying to decode the ridiculously awful documentation for everything from Auth to making requests with the Bing Ads API v2.0 and getting no where.  None of the Oauth 2.0 requests resolve so I can't get past the first step.

Does ANYONE have any example code or guidance?  All I'm trying to do is make a simple reporting query to pull my daily spends!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/ruby) documentation? Which part is not working?

Comment: Please share your code and elaborate on _can't get past the first step_. Is there an error, what does the error message say? What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Sorry everyone - I wasn't clear.  I am looking for help with the Bing ADS Api 2.0.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/get-started?view=bingads-12  If anyone has any code samples, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `accessKey` is wrong? Alternatively you could do something like:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=#{query}").read)
page.css('... a ...').each do |link|
  puts link["href"]
  puts link.text
end
```

For instance, please not that while simple, open-uri is not safe when dealing with user input.

Comment: Sorry I meant Bing Ads API 2.0 not the Bing API